# Remove files older than 5 days in UNIX (date in file name, not timestamp)

Tags: bash, sed, rm

I want to delete log files which are older than 5 days from a directory. But deletion should not be based on the timestamp of file. It should be based on the name of file. For Example todays date is 07/05/2012 and the directory contains 10 files of names like `ABC_20120430.log`, `ABC_20120429.log`, `ABC_20120502.log`, `ABC_20120320.log` etc. I want to be able to remove the files by extracting the date from the name of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on date from filename:

```
THRESHOLD=$(date -d "5 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
ls -1 ABC_????????.log | 
  sed 'h;s/[_.]/ /g;G;s/\n/ /' | 
  while read A DATE B FILE
  do 
     [[ $DATE -le $THRESHOLD ]] && rm -v $FILE
  done
```

Comment: GNU date commands not working.. :( Any other way to get date which is 5 days before?

Answer (score 7):

I think @oHessling *almost* has it: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and you can do more in bash:

```
four_days=$(date -d "4 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
for f in ABC_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].log; do
  date=${f#ABC_}
  date=${date%.log}
  (( $date < $four_days )) && rm "$f"
done
```

Comment: GNU date commands not working.. :( Any other way to get date which is 5 days before?

Comment: @Naren: what OS are you on? If you don't have GNU date, we need to know _what_ you do have.

Comment: With help of uname -a got the following info: "SunOS badap01t 5.10 Generic_141444-09 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise"

Comment: Question remains: what commands do you have available to get the current date?

Comment: If Tcl is installed: `four_days=$(echo "puts [clock format [clock scan {4 days ago}] -format %Y%m%d]" | tclsh)`

Comment: Works like a charm for all files under a given directory. How about recursive?

Comment: @praneel, `shopt -s globstar nullglob; for f in **/ABC...`

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Local qw/timelocal/;
use File::Spec;

## Process all input files.
while ( my $file = shift @ARGV ) { 

    ## Remove last '\n'.
    chomp $file;

    ## Extract date from file name.
    my ($date) = $file =~ m/.*_([^.]+)/ or next;

    ## Extract year, month and day from date.
    my ($y,$m,$d) = $date =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/ or next;

    ## Get date in seconds.
    my $time = timelocal 0, 0, 0, $d, $m - 1, $y - 1900 or next;

    ## Get date in seconds five days ago.
    my $time_5_days_ago = time - 5 * 24 * 3600;

    ## Substract them, and if it is older delete it and print the
    ## event.
    if ( $time - $time_5_days_ago < 0 ) { 
        unlink File::Spec->rel2abs( $file ) and printf qq[%s\n], qq[File $file deleted];
    }   
}
```

To test it I create some files:

```
touch ABC_20120430.log ABC_20120502.log ABC_20120320.log ABC_20120508.log ABC_20120509.log
```

Check them with `ls -1`:

```
ABC_20120320.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ABC_20120430.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ABC_20120502.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ABC_20120508.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ABC_20120509.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
script.pl
```

Run the script like:

```
perl script.pl *.log
```

With following output:

```
File ABC_20120320.log deleted
File ABC_20120430.log deleted
File ABC_20120502.log deleted
```

Answer (score -1):

What you could do instead is use the fact that your filenames will sort in chronological order. For instance, to keep the last 5 files:

```
ls ABC_????????.log | head -n-5 | xargs rm
```

Comment: Don't use xargs with `rm` unless you know you are killing kittens every time you do. It's just a bad idea, if you don't know why do some research and learn that there are always better ways to approach any problem that this could be a solution for.