# How to delete old backups based on a date in file name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, file-management

I have a daily backups named like this:

```
yyyymmddhhmm.zip // pattern
201503200100.zip // backup from 20. 3. 2015 1:00
```

I'm trying to create a script that deletes all backups older than 3 days. The script should be also able to delete all other files in the folder not matching the pattern (but there would be a switch for that in the script to disable this).

To determine the file age I don't want to use backups timestamps as other programs also manipulate with the files and it can be tampered.

With the help of: [Remove files older than 5 days in UNIX (date in file name, not timestamp)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38080/remove-files-older-than-5-days-in-unix-date-in-file-name-not-timestamp)
I got:

```
#!/bin/bash

DELETE_OTHERS=yes
BACKUPS_PATH=/mnt/\!ARCHIVE/\!backups/
THRESHOLD=$(date -d "3 days ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M)

ls -1 ${BACKUPS_PATH}????????????.zip |
  while read A DATE B FILE
  do
     [[ $DATE -le $THRESHOLD ]] && rm -v $BACKUPS_PATH$FILE
  done

if [ $DELETE_OTHERS == "yes" ]; then
    rm ${BACKUPS_PATH}*.* // but I don't know how to not-delete the files matching pattern
fi
```

But it keeps saying:

```
rm: missing operand
```

Where is the problem and how to complete the script?

Comment: Do you actually have a `!` at the beginning of your `ARCHIVE` and `backups` directory names? If so, why in the world would you want to complicate your life in such a way?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm using `!` to keep the one or two key directories on top of the file listings when there is a lot of other files/folders in that directory and it is sorted by name. I am all ears if there is a better technique for that :)

Comment: I just add `aa` or similar to the name, for example `aabackups`. That way, you don't need to escape special characters. It's a matter of personal preference though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first problem in your code is that you are [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). This means it will break very easily, if you have any spaces in your file or directory names for example. You should use shell globbing or `find` instead.

A bigger problem is that you are not reading the data correctly. Your code:

```
ls -1 | while read A DATE B FILE
```

will never populate `$FILE`. The output of `ls -1` is just a list of filenames so, unless those file names contain whitespace, only the first of the 4 variables you give to `read` will be populated.

Here's a working version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DELETE_OTHERS=yes
BACKUPS_PATH=/mnt/\!ARCHIVE/\!backups
THRESHOLD=$(date -d "3 days ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M)

## Find all files in $BACKUPS_PATH. The -type f means only files
## and the -maxdepth 1 ensures that any files in subdirectories are
## not included. Combined with -print0 (separate file names with \0),
## IFS= (don't break on whitespace), "-d ''" (records end on '\0') , it can
## deal with all file names.
find ${BACKUPS_PATH} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0  | while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
    ## Does this file name match the pattern (13 digits, then .zip)?
    if [[ "$(basename "$file")" =~ ^[0-9]{12}.zip$ ]]
    then
        ## Delete the file if it's older than the $THR
        [ "$(basename "$file" .zip)" -le "$THRESHOLD" ] && rm -v -- "$file"
    else
        ## If the file does not match the pattern, delete if 
        ## DELETE_OTHERS is set to "yes"
        [ $DELETE_OTHERS == "yes" ] && rm -v -- "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In FreeBSD use:
Example: find all files in /usr/home/foobar owned by foobar that are older than 5760 minutes (4 days) and delete them.

```
find /usr/home/foobar -user foobar -type f -mmin +5760 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you forget the `sed` line between `ls -1` and  `while read`, this line IS important.

for first question I would suggest: (a awk remplacement I was unable to find a sed equivalent)

```
ls -1 ${BACKUPS_PATH}????????????.zip |\
  awk -F. '{printf "%s %s\n",$1,$0 ;}' |\
  while read DATE FILE
  do
     [[ $DATE -le $THRESHOLD ]] && rm -v $BACKUPS_PATH$FILE
  done
```

provided shell arithmetic are at least 37 bit wise to do the `$DATE -le $THRESHOLD` testing.

Comment: This breaks on whitespace and other strange characters.