# Delete sub-directories with YYYYMMDD in name older than N days

Tags: bash, find, directory, rm, timestamps

I have a directory where daily subdirectories are created, literally named according to `$date`. How can I delete folders and their contents that are older than 7 days **according to the YYYYMMDD in the file name** and not the metadata date? Say I have (skipped some for brevity):

```
20170817
20170823
20170828
20170901
```

I would end up with the following folders (which those should keep):

```
20170828
20170901
```

I created a variable that holds the date 7 days ago:
`` dt_prev=$(date -d "`date`-7days" +%Y%m%d) ``

My thought was to `ls -l` a list of these folder names and compare row by row, but this involves cleaning that list, etc., and I figure there has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution would be a simpler version of what [glenn jackman posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38103/117549), e.g.

```
seven_days=$(date -d "7 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]; do
   [ -d "$f" ] || continue
   (( $f < $seven_days )) && echo rm -r "$f"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the results look correct.

The `-d` test ensures that we only inspect (remove) directories.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff -- this works great. Is there any reason why this would not work via `ssh`? When I `ssh` to a remote server to delete similar sub-directories, the code simply does not work even with absolute paths. It actually tries to find the folder `[0-9]..[0-9]`.



code: `for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]; do
 echo absolute/path/on/remote/server/"$f"
done`




result: `absolute/path/on/remote/server/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: It assumes that you're running that snippet in the directory that has the dated directories in it. either `cd /absolute/path/on/remote/server` first, or prefix the `[0-9]`'s with the /absolute/path

Comment: the `[0-9]` bits are single-digit shell globs, so work in much the same way as `*` or `?` do.

Answer (score 0):

You should not [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), instead you can do something like this:

```
for f in *; do test "$f" -lt "$date" && do something; done
```

For your example, for the following directories and `date=20170825`:

```
$ ls
20170817  20170823  20170828  20170901
$ for f in *; do test "$f" -lt "$date" && echo "$f"; done
20170817
20170823
```

Comment: This may pick up things (not just directories) that have numerical names less than the dates, and it will error out on non-numerical names. _And_ if any name corresponds to a shell variable whose value is numerical, that value will be used...

Comment: The question implies that the directory contains only numbered sub directories, so the solution is a simplified one without checks, but you are right about the file names.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `find` command.

```
find . -type d ! \( -name "$(date -d "-7 days" +%Y%m%d)" \
    $(eval printf "%s" "\" -o -name \
   \$(date -d -"{6..0}"days +%Y%m%d)\"") -o -name . \) -exec rm -rf -- '{}' +
```

- Only **d**iretories`-type d`
- Only directors where their name are in older than 7 days of aging.
- Delete that directory and its contents `rm -rf -- '{}'` at once `+`

Answer (score 0):

With single `find` command:

```
date_week_ago=$(date -d "7 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{8}$' \
       -exec bash -c 'd=$(basename {}); (( '$date_week_ago' > $d )) && rm -rf "$d"' \;
```